# Java calendar date adding and calculation

Tags: java, sql, date, servlets, calendar

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String rn = rs.getString(3);
    String sqldate = rs.getString(2); // database reservation date
    if (rn.equals(rnumber)) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String rdate = (Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + "-" + Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + "-" + Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.DATE)));
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("status.jsp?Status=Reservation number not exist");
    }
}
```

I need to add 7 days to SQL date ( 2012-10-05 +7 ) and need to check those days are in between SQL date and current date.

Comment: Why are you fetching the date as a *string*? And why are you manually formatting the value from the calendar instead of using a SimpleDateFormatter?

Comment: *"help PLZZ"*  Spell words properly please.  I'm going off to help other people that do, to allow you time to think about it.

Comment: I need to add 7 days to SQL date ( 2012-10-05 +7 ) and need to check those days are in between SQL date and current date. SQL gives you date as a String isn't it?

Comment: Is there any ways to add Sql date to java.calender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse your `date` string to create a `java.sql.Date` object: -

```
String sqldate = rs.getString(2);
DateFormat DOB = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.sql.Date convertedDate = new java.sql.Date(DOB.parse(sqldate).getTime());
```

Then use `Calendar.setTime()` method to set `Date` to Calendar instance: -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(convertedDate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
```

Comment: @user1750832 You're welcome. But you should use `JodaTime` which will make your life so much easier while working with Dates.

Comment: Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(converteddate);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
                            
 if(cal<=cal1){
    something                                
 } HOW DO I DO THAT?

Comment: @user1750832. `if (cal.getTimeInMillis() <= cal1.getTimeInMillis())`

Comment: @user1750832.. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()

Comment: @user1750832 Or, [`cal.compareTo(cal1) <= 0`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo(java.util.Calendar))

Answer (score 1):

Use [Joda Time library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net). Its easy to handle date with it.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
```

you can plus days,months,years and find [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). This goind to add in java 8

Comment: But how do i add Sql date to that calender ?

Comment: `java.sql.Date` is subclass of `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Date utilDate =sqlDate; cl.seTime(utilDate);`

Comment: i need to get SQLDATE+7days  BETWEEN date range of current date, any ideas?

Comment: java.util.Date is taking only date objects how do we add strings?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "int days = Days.daysBetween(sqlDate, todaysDate).getDays();" and check if its greater than 7

Comment: i cannot find Days.daysBetween(sqlDate, todaysDate).getDays(); this method